# Images are oversized in Product Description

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

https://shoppaintedturtlehardcider.com/index.php/native-wooden-copper-vacuum-insulated-bottle.html

As you can see from the link, when you click on a product, the image takes up the whole screen. The image is not resizing to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your tag 
`<p class="product-image default-zoom" style="width: 100%">` 
and 
`<img id="image" style="width: 100%">`
  Hope it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following css at your style.css file.

Path:

```
https://shoppaintedturtlehardcider.com/skin/frontend/default/paintedturtle/css/styles.css
```

CSS:

```
.product-image.default-zoom > #image {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your problem follow couple of solution

css

```
 .product-image > #image {
    width: 100%;
 }
```

In your media.phtml add resize method for smaller and resized image write below code in src

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
   ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
   ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
   ->keepFrame(FALSE)
   ->resize(400,400); //size of image 
?>
```

there are lots of problem in your in your theme.

Just like eleventzoom is not working,

image is not resized so page load time would increase

css js is not merged